# How to Update Customer Password using Magento SOAP API v2

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I am using Magento SOAP API v2 for web services. 
I want to update customer password API.

For this I have created a function as follows :

```
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'email',
            'value' => array('key' => 'eq', 'value' => $customer_email)
        )
    )
);
$customerData = $soapClient->customerCustomerList($sessionId, $complexFilter);
$match = customerPasswordMatching($customer_old_pwd,$customerData[0]->password_hash);       //it return true if password match
if($match == TRUE)
{
    $customerInfo = array(
        'firstname' => $first_name,
        'password' => $customer_new_pwd, 
        'website_id' => $customerData[0]->website_id, 
        'store_id' => $customerData[0]->store_id, 
        'group_id' => $customerData[0]->group_id);

    $result = $soapClient->customerCustomerUpdate($sessionId, $customer_id ,$customerInfo );
    return $result;         
}
else
{
    return array('Success' => 0, 'Message' => 'Wrong Password');
}
```

This code update customer 'firstname' but not update customer password.

Any one can provide me details how can I update customer password in Magento soap API v2?

Answer (score 1):

You've to create a module for this to get it working:

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_ChangePasswordWithApi>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vendor_ChangePasswordWithApi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_api>Vendor_ChangePasswordWithApi_Model_Customer_Api</customer_api>
                    <customer_api_v2>Vendor_ChangePasswordWithApi_Model_Customer_Api_V2</customer_api_v2>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Model/Customer/Api.php**

```
<?php
class Vendor_ChangePasswordWithApi_Model_Customer_Api extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api
{
    public function update($customerId, $customerData)
    {
        $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData);

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($customer) as $attributeCode=>$attribute) {
            if (isset($customerData[$attributeCode])) {
                $customer->setData($attributeCode, $customerData[$attributeCode]);
            }
        }

        // Added password support
        if(isset($customerData['password'])){
            $customer->setPassword($customerData['password']);
        }
        //

        $customer->save();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Model/Customer/Api/V2.php**

```
<?php
class Vendor_ChangePasswordWithApi_Model_Customer_Api_V2 extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api_V2 {

    public function update($customerId, $customerData)
    {
        $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData);

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }

        foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($customer) as $attributeCode=>$attribute) {
            if (isset($customerData[$attributeCode])) {
                $customer->setData($attributeCode, $customerData[$attributeCode]);
            }
        }

        // Added password support
        if(isset($customerData['password'])){
            $customer->setPassword($customerData['password']);
        }
        //

        $customer->save();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've striped this code out of a project of mine, that project is on EE 1.14.2.0. So maybe it needs some changes for other versions. Check the original `update()` functions in the `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api` and `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api_V2` classes. I've only added the commented part:

```
if(isset($customerData['password'])){
    $customer->setPassword($customerData['password']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you tell me how to call `update` function in my webservice?

Comment: It just works with your example code. The code is used by the `customerCustomerUpdate()` function your using.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function to update customer password via Custom Magento API :

```
/* This method is responsible to update customer account password 
    @Ahsan Horani
*/
public function changePassword($info)
{
    $customer_email         =   $info['customer_email'];    
    $customer_old_pswd      =   $info['customer_old_pswd'];     
    $customer_new_pswd  =   $info['customer_new_pswd'];     

    try
    {
        //Authenticate User Email and Old Password
        $authenticate   =   Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(1)->authenticate($customer_email, $customer_old_pswd);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        return "fail";  //Failed authentication
    }

    if($authenticate)
    {
        //Load Customer by Email
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(1); //Customers are based on Website
        $customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);

        // Check if customer exists
        if ($customer->getId()) 
        {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
            $customer->setEmail($customer_email);
            $customer->setPassword($customer_new_pswd);

            try 
            {
                $customer->save();
                return "success";
            } 
            catch (Exception $ex) 
            {
                return "error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

Use below code to call custom API from external script e.g. from **Slim framework**

```
// GET route
$app->post(
  '/change-password',

function () use ($app) {
    $info['customer_email']     = $app->request()->post('email');
    $info['customer_new_pswd']  = $app->request()->post('new_password');
    $info['customer_old_pswd']  = $app->request()->post('old_password');

    $msg    =   'Password updated successfully';    //Default message

    if($info['customer_email'] == "" || $info['customer_old_pswd'] == "" ||  $info['customer_new_pswd'] == "")
    {
        $msg            =   'Please provide proper customer info';
        $responseData    =   array('message'=>$msg,'status'=>'error');
        $responseData    =   json_encode($responseData);
        print_r($responseData);
        die();
    }

    try
    {
        if ($info['customer_email'] && $info['customer_old_pswd'] &&  $info['customer_new_pswd'])
        {
            $response = changePassword($info);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $msg            =   $e->getMessage();
        $responseData    =  array('message'=>$msg,'status'=>'error');
        $responseData    =  json_encode($responseData);
        print_r($responseData);
        die();
    }

    if($response == 'error')
    {
        $msg    =   'Unable to update password';
    }
    else if($response == 'fail')
    {
        $msg    =   'Wrong Password';
    }

    $responseData    =   array('message'=>$msg,'status'=>$response);
    $responseData    =   json_encode($responseData);

    print_r($responseData); //Print response from API
 }
);

/* Change customer password using custom API */
 function changePassword($info)
 {
  $client_v1 = new SoapClient(MAGENTO_API_URL);
  $session_id_v1 = $client_v1->login(MAGENTO_API_V2_USERNAME,     MAGENTO_API_V2_PASSWORD);
  $responseData = $client_v1->call($session_id_v1, 'customapi.changePassword',array($info));
  return $responseData;
}
```